# Citation feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Is it possible to re-enable the "cite" feature from MO (and later MSE)?

(I'd like to remind the users, in the case this is going to be enabled, that the feature now hides within the "share" button, and does not have a button of its own.)

Comment: This should not be too hard, as it is also enabled on other more academic SE sites like Physics.SE

Comment: @Willie: That makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The citation feature has been enabled on your main site.  Enjoy!

Comment: Huzzah! (Although in fairness, it should be "re-enabled" :-))

Comment: Could we make it more obvious? You need a magnifying glass to see it!