# Can we make the cite link bigger?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, citations

The cite link in the share box is minuscule:

[image: Share box screenshot]

Since this is a very important feature for MO, it should have much more visibility.

[Related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/112, [Citation feature](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/71/)]

Comment: Checking on the possibility of this now, will get back with a proper answer (or implementation) soon.

Comment: @TimPost, ping! The cite link is really important to us. MathOverflow is being widely cited in the published literature, and we need to make it as easy as possible to do this properly.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Sorry, slipped through the cracks. I'm pinging Jin about this right now.

Answer (score 14):

After letting this slip through the cracks for a couple of years, I'm pleased say we've implemented [Scott Morrison's solution](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1444/36770):

[image: Firstclass cite link.]

(Ignore the "mod" link if you aren't a moderator.)

We did talk about replacing the share link, but decided it was potentially confusing for users of other sites. Currently the citations are active on the following sites:

- Computer Science Theory
- Math
- MathOverflow
- Physics

Especially for the Physics and CS folks, it would be confusing to move the share link too much. Personally, I use it to generate a short link to answers all the time and would not want it to move around depending on what site I'm on. Puting the "cite" link just after "share" seems like a reasonable compromise to me.

Comment: If you like the cite button, you might also be interested in [trackbacks from SE to the arXiv.org](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520/209806) beyond MO.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to see the 'cite' link restored to its 1.0 level of visibility. It should appear in the line of links as:

mod cite share edit close delete flag

(or, perhaps, even replace the 'share' link!)

Comment: I'm not 100% about replacing the share link, but I'd definitely want to see it right there with the rest of the buttons. Somehow, though, I doubt either of these wishes are going to be granted any time soon. :\

Comment: I would like to add my voice to the request for replacing the 'share' link.

Comment: I would be sad to see the 'share' link go. It generates a shorter URL that is more easily pasted into e-mails etc. I know I can do it by hand, but it is nice to be able to right-click and "copy link address".

Comment: @Willie Wong, I distinctly remember there used to be a permalink beneath each answer. I am of the opinion that the permalink was vastly better than the 'share' button we have now. The permalink (together with the cite button) was what I was implicitly thinking about when I suggested replacing the 'share' link.