# How did I earn the Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges

Description of the [Announcer badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/54/announcer) reads

> Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I have just earned the fourth one. And for none of them do I actually remember when and how did I share a link that later resulted in my earning this badge. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: I am not sure about the details, but sometimes even links within the Stack Exchange network might contribute to this badge: [I received the Announcer badge for a link to a site-meta shared on a hot network question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242864) and [Publicity badges might be taking internal links into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134185) When I look at the questions [for which you have the Announcer badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/54/announcer?userid=41291), I see that you have mentioned the most recent one ...

Comment: ... in a [comment on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250152/abc-conjecture-and-fermats-last-theorem#comment615869_250152). As a side note, you can avoid getting this badge if you use link without your user id. A related older discussion: [Privacy of software-generated links to questions and answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2167). More details on various ways to link to a MO post: [Distinguishing between questions and answers in references.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3586#30814)

Comment: @MartinSleziak you are extraordinarily helpful, as always! But how did you find that comment of mine??

Comment: Oh I see - the "Linked" list on the right? Should think of it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Generally, only links from outside the network should count for [publicity badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/publicity-badges/info) (Announcer, Booster and Publisher). But it seems that there are some technical reasons which might cause that sometimes visits from links within the network count too.</s>
It used to be the case that only links from outside the network contributed to [publicity badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/publicity-badges/info) (Announcer, Booster and Publisher). Since the switch to HTTPS, the links within the network count too. (But even before that, they might have had some effect for technical reasons.) You can find some more details in some posts on Meta Stack Exchange related to this topic: [I received the Announcer badge for a link to a site-meta shared on a hot network question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242864), [Publicity badges might be taking internal links into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134185) or [Won Announcer badge even without sharing the link externally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327156).

---

I think this might be plausible explanation in your case. At the moment you have [four Announcer badges](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/54/announcer?userid=41291). You have linked somewhere on MO to those posts:

- Link to [Effect of abc conjecture on Fermat's Last Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/130980) in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250152/abc-conjecture-and-fermats-last-theorem#comment615869_250152).
- Link to [What is known about the sum x^{n^2}/n?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146139) in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198088/efficiently-computing-plethysm-likesubstitutions-of-symmetric-functions).
- Link to [your answer for Prime factorization “demoted” leads to function whose fixed points are primes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177759#177773) in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55200/good-programs-for-drawing-graphs-directed-weighted-graphs/55263#comment464442_55263).
- Link to [The number of pairings between multisets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/67359) in several comments: [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198423/an-inequality-concerning-non-negative-integer-matrices-with-constant-row-and-col#comment492747_198423), [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33273/combinations-of-multisets-with-finite-multiplicities#comment538183_33273), [three](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225678/counting-specific-permutations-of-elements-in-a-multiset#comment557167_225678).

---

You can avoid these badges if you use link without your user id. This discussion is related (to some extent): [Privacy of software-generated links to questions and answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2167). I have mentioned various ways how to link to Stack Exchange post in my answer on Mathematics Meta: [Distinguishing between questions and answers in references.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3586#30814)

---

This is only tangential, but since you asked how I found your comment. Initially I tried to [google for "https://mathoverflow.net/q/130980/41291"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22https://mathoverflow.net/q/130980/41291%22). (Just to check whether in this way I can find some places where the post is shared with your user id.) But if you suspect that links are on this site, then you can search for posts containing the given url and [restrict the search to a specific user](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22*%2F146139%2F*%22+user%3A41291). To search in comments by a specific user, you have to use [Data Explorer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info), here is an [example of such query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1074444/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-a-given-word?userid=41291&word=67359). See also: [Searching for comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3247).